# Python threading.Timer проблема c перезапуском потока после его отмены

Tags: python, многопоточность, таймер

В общем есть код:

```
def delayed(j):
    print('end '+ str(j))
    return
t = threading.Timer(120, delayed, [j])
t.start()
.............
t.cancel()
```

Суть проблемы в том, что когда второй раз срабатывает t.start() после t.cancel(), отсчет идет не с начала, а с того времени, что было во время срабатывания t.cancel()

Comment: *The timer can be stopped (before its action has begun) by calling the cancel() method.* В моём понимании *остановка*, это на самом деле *приостановка*. Чтобы начинать совсем заново, вам надо делать что-то типа `del t; t = threading.Timer(); t.start()` или не пользоваться `.cancel()` вообще.

Comment: 0andriy Не помогло

Answer (score 1):

> Суть проблемы в том, что когда второй раз срабатывает t.start() после t.cancel(), отсчет идет не с начала, а с того времени, что было во время срабатывания t.cancel()

`Timer` это `Thread`, поэтому нельзя больше одного раза `.start()` метод вызвать (должны получить `RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")` при втором вызове).

Если вы хотите перезапустить Timer, то либо новый создайте или используйте реализацию, которая поддерживает `.restart()` метод, такую как [`WatchdogTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115590/4279).